# Final parameter in a method in java

Tags: java, methods, final

I have 2 questions with this code segments

1. method 1 is working fine and method 2 doesn't. What is the reason for this?
2. In method 1 return value is byte(8 bit). But we actually return a char value(16 bit).
   what is actually happening here?

//method 1

```
static byte m1() {
    final char c = 'b'-'a';
    return c; 
}
```

//method 2

```
static byte m3(final char c) {
    return c; // 3
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: when it compiles it says :: error: possible loss of precision

Comment: Perhaps static optimization in method 1 ?

Comment: And what is not clear with this error message? Do you understand that chars are 16-bits long, whereas bytes are 8-bits long?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`char` in Java is a *16 bit unsigned* value, while `byte` is *8 bit signed* value. Allowed range for byte is `[-128, 127]`. So, not all character can be assigned in `byte`.

In your first method, you are returning a `char` with *code point = 1* (`'b' - 'a'`). Now since you have defined `char` as `final`, and assigning to it a constant expression, it becomes a compile time constant. So, compiler doesn't give any compiler error.

From [JLS Section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> If the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>       - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and **the value of the constant expression is representable** in the type of the variable.

Emphasis mine.

However, if you make `c` non-final, it will also result in a compiler error:

```
static byte m1() {  // This will be an error
    char c = 'b'-'a';
    return c; 
}
```

The reason is, `c` is not a compile time constant any more, and compiler doesn't do an implicit downcast.

In 2nd method you are returning the `char` that you passed. The parameter `c` there is not a compile time constant. It isn't known at compile time what value the method might get. 
Like, if you pass a `char` with code points not in range of allowed `byte` value, it won't work.

To make the 2nd method work, you can do an explicit cast:

```
static byte m3(final char c) {
    return (byte)c; // 3
}
```

Comment: Ohh! in which company you are ?

Comment: I am in iGATE...Looking for a Ruby job...Can you help me? :)

Answer (score 2):

In `m1()` the compiler sees that `char c` is constant with value `1` and therefore does not complain as it knows it can be fit into byte. If you changed it to `final char c = 128` where 127 is the maximum size of the `byte` you would get complaint, as you also would when you removed the `final`variable descriptor from `char c`.

Comment: can you explain why an error is occured when the final keyword is deleted?

Comment: When you remove `final` it is no longer a constant. So compiler cannot be sure that it will not change in the future (even though the method end in the next line, the compiler is not aware of this). When there is `final char c` with assigned value, compiler just sees it as number 127 which has no problem to be safely transformed into any integer type. Remember that `char` in java ranges from 0 - 65 535 as it has 16 bits. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

In method 2, the compiler cannot make a narrowing implicit cast from chat to byte, because it could result in a loss of precision (Java supports Unicode characters, and its char primitive type is defined with the size of 16-bits of information, differently from C language where it is usually 8 bits)

In method 1 though, the compiler can determine that the constant value 'b'-'a' will not actually result in a loss of precision, and so allows you to perform the implicit cast.

Take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 0):

Now the reason `m1()` works and `m3()` doesn't is because in `m1()` c is a `compile-time constant`.

Analyse this code:

```
    byte b = 'x'; //compile-time constant
    int i = 'x'; //compile-time constant
    char c = 'x'; //compile-time constant
    c = i; //compilation error
    c = b; //compilation error
    b = i; //compilation error
    b = c; //compilation error
    i = b;  // Okay
    i = c;  // Okay
```

Compiler will not do an implicit cast which can possibly result in loss of data, for run-time variables.